# Operation along year with xarray

Tags: grouping, python-xarray

I'd like to perform the mean (and quantiles) along the years on an xarray.

If the time sampling is multiple of days, I can easy do something like that:

```
arr.groupby('time.dayofyear').mean('time')
```

But I can't find an easy way to do the same if I have got also hours. (Now I'm using an horrible trick).

For example in this case:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import xarray as xr

time = pd.date_range('2000-01-01', '2010-01-01', freq='6h')
arr = xr.DataArray(
     np.ones(len(time)), 
     dims='time', 
     coords={'time' : ('time', time)}
)
```

Probably I'm missing something, I'm not very expert on pandas and xarray. Have you got some tips?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

If you want daily averages, `resample` is the best tool for the job:

```
daily = arr.resample(time='D').mean('time')
```

Then, you can use groupby to calculate quantiles for each day of year:

```
quantiles_by_dayofyear = daily.groupby('time.dayofyear').apply(
    xr.DataArray.quantile, q=[0.25, 0.5, 0.75])

print(quantiles_by_dayofyear)
```

Yields:

```
<xarray.DataArray (dayofyear: 366, quantile: 3)>
array([[1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1.],
       ...,
       [1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1.]])
Coordinates:
  * quantile   (quantile) float64 0.25 0.5 0.75
  * dayofyear  (dayofyear) int64 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 ...
```

We should probably add the quantile method to xarray's list of groupby reduce methods but this should work for now.

Answer (score 0):

For the daily average I would suggest to use the resample function. In case I understood the question correctly, this should give you daily averages. You can then use these daily averages to compute your groupby dayofyear operation.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import xarray as xr

time = pd.date_range('2000-01-01', '2010-01-01', freq='6h')
arr = xr.DataArray(
     np.ones(len(time)), 
     dims='time', 
     coords={'time' : ('time', time)}
)

daily = arr.resample(time='D').mean('time')
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, probably my question was not clear. Consider only the quantiles.
My expected output is something like that:

```
<xarray.DataArray (hours: 1464, quantile: 3)>
array([[1., 1., 1.],
      [1., 1., 1.],
      [1., 1., 1.],
      ...,
      [1., 1., 1.],
      [1., 1., 1.],
      [1., 1., 1.]])
Coordinates:
* quantile   (quantile) float64 0.25 0.5 0.75
* hours  (hours) int64 6 12 18 24 30 36 42 48 54 60 66 72 ...
```

Where hours are the hours from the beginning of the year. But instead of hours it could be good also something like a multiindex with dayofyear and hour (of day). I've got a tricky way to do it (Performing some rendexing With multindexing and unstack  the time dimension), but it's really horrible. I think that there is easier and elegant way to do it.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of the question is that you either want to be able to do a groupby operation over two variables simulataneously, or groupby something that is not a method of the xarray DateTimeAccessor.

Something you might look at is using `xarray.apply_ufunc`. Below is some code that I used for getting grouped means by year and by month.

```
def _grouped_mean(
            data: np.ndarray,
            months: np.ndarray,
            years: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
        """similar to grouping year_month MultiIndex, but faster.

        Should be used wrapped by _wrapped_grouped_mean"""
        unique_months = np.sort(np.unique(months))
        unique_years = np.sort(np.unique(years))
        old_shape = list(data.shape)
        new_shape = old_shape[:-1]
        new_shape.append(unique_months.shape[0])
        new_shape.append(unique_years.shape[0])

        output = np.zeros(new_shape)

        for i_month, j_year in np.ndindex(output.shape[2:]):
            indices = np.intersect1d(
                (months == unique_months[i_month]).nonzero(),
                (years == unique_years[j_year]).nonzero()
            )

            output[:, :, i_month, j_year] =\
                np.mean(data[:, :, indices], axis=-1)

        return output

def _wrapped_grouped_mean(da: xr.DataArray) -> xr.DataArray:
        """similar to grouping by a year_month MultiIndex, but faster.

        Wraps a numpy-style function with xr.apply_ufunc
        """
        Y = xr.apply_ufunc(
            _grouped_mean,
            da,
            da.time.dt.month,
            da.time.dt.year,
            input_core_dims=[['lat', 'lon', 'time'], ['time'], ['time']],
            output_core_dims=[['lat', 'lon', 'month', 'year']],
        )
        Y = Y.assign_coords(
            {'month': np.sort(np.unique(da.time.dt.month)),
             'year': np.sort(np.unique(da.time.dt.year))})
        return Y
```